# SQL Loop doesn't loop

Tags: sql-server, loops, t-sql

I have to repeat a specific bit of code for each month, so I thought to build a loop.

```
DECLARE @Startdate DATE = '20200101';
DECLARE @Enddate   DATE = '20210101';

WHILE (@Startdate < @Enddate) 
BEGIN
    SELECT Rapportagedatum, Boekdatum, Rekeningnr, Bedrag, Uw_referentie         
    FROM FC_GBRMUT (nolock) 
    WHERE RekeningNr = 14050  
      AND MONTH(Rapportagedatum) = MONTH(@Startdate) 
      AND YEAR(Rapportagedatum) = YEAR(@Startdate)
      AND Boekdatum < @Startdate

    SET @Startdate = DATEADD(m, 1, @Startdate)
END
```

Now the problem is that it refuses to loop. If I remove the `AND Boekdatum < @Startdate` it shows that only January is pulled from the database.

How do I fix it so that it loops for the entire year?

Comment: Why you not use between operator?

Comment: The loop is working for me. If you run this `WHILE  (@Startdate < @Enddate) 
BEGIN
    SELECT @Startdate
    SET @Startdate = DATEADD(m,1,@Startdate)
END` you should get 12 dates.

Comment: Lets take a step back. Why are you using `WHILE` loop and what do you want to achieve ?

Comment: And why are you using `nolock`?

Comment: WHat I want to achieve is that I get an overview of the balance per Reportingmonth while the bookingdate contains the months before that. 

If the loop works for you it's my systems that have the problem, thank you.

The nolock is essential otherwise it will prohibit others in Finance accessing our bookkeepingprogram.

Answer (score 1):

Why even bother with a loop??

Just write it in one, simple statement:

```
SELECT Rapportagedatum, Boekdatum, Rekeningnr, Bedrag, Uw_referentie         
FROM FC_GBRMUT
WHERE RekeningNr = 14050  
  AND Boekdatum BETWEEN @StartDate AND @Enddate
```

Done! No looping, no unnecessary RBAR (row-by-agonizing-row) processing

Comment: Well.. because for each month I need the Balance at Reportingdate while the bookingdate lies before the Reportingdate.

Answer (score 0):

I see no reason on why this would not work unless you get an error. 
I've tested the query below

```
DECLARE @Startdate      DATE = '20200101';
DECLARE @Enddate        DATE = '20210101';

WHILE  (@Startdate < @Enddate) 
BEGIN
    SELECT @Startdate
    SET @Startdate = DATEADD(m,1,@Startdate)
END
```

Answer (score 0):

As all the others already mentioned the Loop is working for me. I am wondering why you are using a WHILE LOOP in the first place, but let's not question this for now.

I created the following minimal example. Let's assume your data looks similar, then your results would return nothing because of Boekdatum is not smaller than StartDate for each Loop, but equals StartDate. Therefore in the line `AND Boekdatum <= @Startdate` I replaced `=` with `<=` and I removed `(nolock)`. Maybe this will resolve your "not working" LOOP.

```
DECLARE @FC_GBRMUT table (Rapportagedatum date, Boekdatum date , Rekeningnr int , Bedrag varchar(100), Uw_referentie varchar(100))

INSERT INTO @FC_GBRMUT
SELECT '20200101', '20200101', 14050, 'RandomText', 'RandomText'
UNION SELECT '20200201', '20200201', 14050, 'RandomText', 'RandomText'
UNION SELECT '20200301', '20200301', 14050, 'RandomText', 'RandomText'
UNION SELECT '20200401', '20200401', 14050, 'RandomText', 'RandomText'
UNION SELECT '20200501', '20200501', 14050, 'RandomText', 'RandomText'
UNION SELECT '20200601', '20200601', 14050, 'RandomText', 'RandomText'
UNION SELECT '20200701', '20200701', 14050, 'RandomText', 'RandomText'
UNION SELECT '20200801', '20200801', 14050, 'RandomText', 'RandomText'
UNION SELECT '20200901', '20200901', 14050, 'RandomText', 'RandomText'
UNION SELECT '20201001', '20201001', 14050, 'RandomText', 'RandomText'
UNION SELECT '20201101', '20201101', 14050, 'RandomText', 'RandomText'
UNION SELECT '20201201', '20201201', 14050, 'RandomText', 'RandomText'

DECLARE @Startdate DATE = '20200101';
DECLARE @Enddate DATE = '20210101';

WHILE (@Startdate < @Enddate) 
BEGIN
SELECT Rapportagedatum, Boekdatum, Rekeningnr, Bedrag, Uw_referentie 
FROM @FC_GBRMUT --(nolock) 
WHERE RekeningNr =14050 
AND Month(Rapportagedatum) = MONTH(@Startdate) AND Year(Rapportagedatum) = YEAR(@Startdate)
AND Boekdatum <= @Startdate
SET @Startdate = DATEADD(m,1,@Startdate)
END
```